# Jquery Focus on dropdown is not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have trouble trying to figure out the dropdown for my list.It is similar to ul li:hover ul li.What im trying to figure out is like ul li:focus ul li but in jquery since i dont think doing it in css works.The goal im trying to get at is when i click on the ul li the ul li drops down.

Html

```
<nav id="navbar">
  <div class="dropdown-btn">Go To...</div>
  <ul class="navbar-tab">
    <li class="navbar-tab-1 selected">Home</li>
    <li class="navbar-tab-1 select">Searches
      <ul class="hover-list select">
        <li><a>Search</a></li>
        <li><a>Rocks</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar-tab-1 select">Engagement Rings
      <ul class="hover-list select">
        <li><a>Verragio</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar-tab-1 select">Services
      <ul class="hover-list select">
        <li><a href="">Repair</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

jquery

```
$(".navbar-tab-1").focus(function(){
  $(".hoverlist li").css("display","block").fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/focus/ `li`s cannot gain focus.

Comment: Your `class` seems to be named `.hover-list`.

Comment: @AjAX. oh ye sorry since ive been switching back and forth i keep the class names the same

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues in your code:

1. `focus` do not work with the `ul` element. You can use `hover` for that.
2. You need to change your class selector to `.hover-list` instead of `.hoverlist`
3. You should initially set `display:none` to all `.hover-list` elements so that when you hover over the `ul` they are displayed.
4. Use `fadeIn()` to show them in fade in effect.
5. You can use `cursor: pointer;` css for you `ul` elements to have a proper cursor pointer for the links

```js
$(".navbar-tab-1").hover(function(){
  $('.hover-list').css("display","none");
  $(this).find(".hover-list").css("display","block").fadeIn();
});
```

```css
.hover-list{
  display: none;
}
.navbar-tab-1{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="navbar">
    <div class="dropdown-btn">Go To...</div>
    <ul class="navbar-tab">
        <li class="navbar-tab-1 selected">Home</li>
        <li class="navbar-tab-1 select">Searches
            <ul class="hover-list select">
                <li><a>Search</a></li>
                <li><a>Rocks</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar-tab-1 select">Engagement Rings
            <ul class="hover-list select">
                <li><a>Verragio</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar-tab-1 select">Services
            <ul class="hover-list select">
                <li><a href="">Repair</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

If you also want to hide the `li` items when mouse is not hovering over the `ul` then you can use the `mouseover` and `mouseout` event instead of `hover`:

```js
$(".navbar-tab-1").mouseover(function(){
  $('.hover-list').css("display","none");
  $(this).find(".hover-list").css("display","block").fadeIn();
});

$(".navbar-tab-1").mouseout(function(){
  $('.hover-list').css("display","none");
});
```

```css
.hover-list{
  display: none;
}
.navbar-tab-1{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="navbar">
    <div class="dropdown-btn">Go To...</div>
    <ul class="navbar-tab">
        <li class="navbar-tab-1 selected">Home</li>
        <li class="navbar-tab-1 select">Searches
            <ul class="hover-list select">
                <li><a>Search</a></li>
                <li><a>Rocks</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar-tab-1 select">Engagement Rings
            <ul class="hover-list select">
                <li><a>Verragio</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar-tab-1 select">Services
            <ul class="hover-list select">
                <li><a href="">Repair</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```